# Regex to extract date from text

Tags: regex

My text file contains thousands of lines with a timestamp in it.

Following is format:

```
141.243.1.172 [29:23:53:25] "GET /Software.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1497
```

where my timestamp is `[29:23:53:25]`

What regular expression is needed to identify this pattern? I tried the below pattern but it is not working as expected.

```
    regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\[(\d\d\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4})]', 1)
```

Comment: Your pattern seems to have elements designed *not* to match the example you give - i.e. `/\w{3}\/\d{4}` and ` -\d{4}` - remove those and it should match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegExp: `r"\[(\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)\]"`

The `\d+` are designated to match the four numbers and are separated with semicolon accordingly.

```
import re

text = '141.243.1.172 [29:23:53:25] "GET /Software.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1497\n141.243.1.172 [29:45:65:25] "GET /Software.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1497'
matches = re.findall(r"\[(\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)\]", text)

for m in matches:
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
29:23:53:25
29:45:65:25
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text file contains many timestamps, then I would refer you to Yaniv's answer. If you know that there is only a single timestamp in the file, then I would suggest instead using

```
matches = re.search(r"\[\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\]", text)
```

The reason being that #findall will scan the entirety of the text, which is sub-optimal if there is only a single occurrence (especially if it's at the beginning).